# Inputting the static properties into the object variable

Tags: javascript, object, properties, static

I want to make it so in the input box, when it is entered, the values are assigned to properties in the object variable, but the properties have to be static.
For example: 
If for the weight you input 180, the value of 180 is assigned to the weight. I'm having trouble figuring out how to make the inputted properties static.   Also not sure how to display the key and the values. Right now I have it so it's in the console.

My current code is

```js
var basketballplayers = {
  weight: "",
  height: "",
  wins: "",
  losses: "",
};

document.getElementById('number').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    let pikachu = this.value;
    console.log(pikachu);
    document.getElementById("charzard").innerHTML = pikachu;
  }
});

document.getElementById('number1').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    let pikachu1 = this.value;
    console.log(pikachu1);
    document.getElementById("charzard1").innerHTML = pikachu1;

  }
});

document.getElementById('number2').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    let pikachu2 = this.value;
    console.log(pikachu2);
    document.getElementById("charzard2").innerHTML = pikachu2;

  }
});

document.getElementById('number3').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    let pikachu3 = this.value;
    console.log(pikachu3);
    document.getElementById("charzard3").innerHTML = pikachu3;

  }
});









for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(basketballplayers)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

```html
<h1>Basketball Players</h1>
<p id="zip"></p>

<p>Weight:</p><input type="number" id="number" />
<p id="charzard"></p>
<p>Height:</p><input type="number" id="number1" />
<p id="charzard1"></p>
<p>Wins:</p><input type="number" id="number2" />
<p id="charzard2"></p>
<p>Losses:</p><input type="number" id="number3" />
<p id="charzard3"></p>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "static"?

Comment: Hey, not sure how to explain so i'm going to link this article: https://javascript.info/static-properties-methods#static-properties but basically static properties look like regular class properties, but they have static before them. Also, the static makes it so the same property can be read from anywhere else in the web page, and so it can be globally accessed.

Comment: But you don't have any classes, just an object. And why do you care if they're static anyway?

Comment: Nevermind, they don't need to be static.